# ¿Como extraer una cantidad definida de arrays en un array bidimensional con php?

Tags: php, array

Partiendo de la siguiente situacion:
Tengo la clasificacion de una liga de futbol almacenado en un array bidimensional, el orden de los arrays es el mismo que la posicion que ocupan en la clasificacion global, a demas en la segunda dimension del array junto con los datos de nombre de equipo, escuto, id's etc. Tambien incluye la posicion (pos).
Necesito sacar un array que contenga bloques de 5 arrays en la primera dimension, en funcion del equipo seleccionado con las siguentes condiciones:
Si la posicion del equipo seleccionado es menor de 4, muestra los 5 primeros.
Si la posicion del equipo seleccionado es mayor de 17, muestra los 5 ultimos.
Si la posicion del equipo seleccionado esta entre 4 y 17, los dos incluidos (>= y <= respectivamente) muestra los dos por encima y los dos por debajo del equipo seleccionado.
Tabla clasificación:

1   Real Madrid

2   Barcelona

3   Real Betis

4   Villarreal

5   Athletic

6   Atlético

7   Osasuna

8   Girona

9   Rayo Vallecano

10  Celta

11  R. Sociedad

12  Valencia

13  Mallorca

14  Almería

15  Espanyol

16  Sevilla

17  Real Valladolid

18  Getafe

19  Elche

20  Cádiz

supongamos que elijo el 3, Real Betis. La extracion debe contener:

1. Real Madrid
2. Barcelona
3. Real Betis
4. Villarreal
5. Athletic

pero si elegimos el 4 Villareal, la seleccion deberia contener:

2. Barcelona
3. Real Betis
4. Villarreal
5. Athletic
6. Atlético

Lo mismo por la parte de abajo de la tabla, si elegimos el 18 Getafe, la extraccion contnendría:

16. Sevilla
17. Real Valladolid
18. Getafe
19. Elche
20. Cádiz

y en cambio si elegimos 17 Real Valladolid, la seleccion deberia contener:

15. Espanyol
16. Sevilla
17. Real Valladolid
18. Getafe
19. Elche

estoy en este punto:

```
<?php

$table = array(
    array('id'=>'25','name'=>'Real Madrid','shield'=>'1234','pos'=>'1'),
    array('id'=>'35','name'=>'Barcelona','shield'=>'1267','pos'=>'2'),
    array('id'=>'45','name'=>'Real Betis','shield'=>'1254','pos'=>'3'),
    array('id'=>'55','name'=>'Villarreal','shield'=>'1285','pos'=>'4'),
    array('id'=>'65','name'=>'Athletic','shield'=>'1296','pos'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'75','name'=>'Atlético','shield'=>'1264','pos'=>'6'),
    array('id'=>'85','name'=>'Osasuna','shield'=>'1265','pos'=>'7'),
    array('id'=>'105','name'=>'Girona','shield'=>'1236','pos'=>'8'),
    array('id'=>'110','name'=>'Rayo Vallecano','shield'=>'1298','pos'=>'9'),
    array('id'=>'10','name'=>'Celta','shield'=>'1274','pos'=>'10'),
    array('id'=>'15','name'=>'R. Sociedad','shield'=>'1342','pos'=>'11'),
    array('id'=>'20','name'=>'Valencia','shield'=>'3214','pos'=>'12'),
    array('id'=>'30','name'=>'Mallorca','shield'=>'1478','pos'=>'13'),
    array('id'=>'40','name'=>'Almería','shield'=>'1463','pos'=>'14'),
    array('id'=>'50','name'=>'Espanyol','shield'=>'1345','pos'=>'15'),
    array('id'=>'60','name'=>'Sevilla','shield'=>'1465','pos'=>'16'),
    array('id'=>'70','name'=>'Real Valladolid','shield'=>'1436','pos'=>'17'),
    array('id'=>'80','name'=>'Getafe','shield'=>'1678','pos'=>'18'),
    array('id'=>'90','name'=>'Elche','shield'=>'8976','pos'=>'19'),
    array('id'=>'100','name'=>'Cádiz','shield'=>'15632','pos'=>'20'),
);

function miniTable($clasificacion, $equipo)
{
    $clave = array_search($equipo, array_column($clasificacion, 'name'));
    $posicion = $clasificacion[$clave];
    $minitabla = [];

    if ($posicion < 4) {
        // What can i do?...
    } elseif ($posicion > 17) {
        // What can i do?...
    } elseif ($posicion > 3 && $posicion < 18) {
        // What can i do?...
    }

    return $minitabla;
}

$equiposelect = miniTable($table,'Osasuna');

var_dump($equiposelect);
```

El resultado de este ejemplo deberia ser:

```
$equiposelect = array(
    array('id'=>'65','name'=>'Athletic','shield'=>'1296','pos'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'75','name'=>'Atlético','shield'=>'1264','pos'=>'6'),
    array('id'=>'85','name'=>'Osasuna','shield'=>'1265','pos'=>'7'),
    array('id'=>'105','name'=>'Girona','shield'=>'1236','pos'=>'8'),
    array('id'=>'110','name'=>'Rayo Vallecano','shield'=>'1298','pos'=>'9')
);
```

Si cogieramos el Barcelona por ejemplo, la solucion deberia de ser:

```
$minitable = array(
    array('id'=>'25','name'=>'Real Madrid','shield'=>'1234','pos'=>'1'),
    array('id'=>'35','name'=>'Barcelona','shield'=>'1267','pos'=>'2'),
    array('id'=>'45','name'=>'Real Betis','shield'=>'1254','pos'=>'3'),
    array('id'=>'55','name'=>'Villarreal','shield'=>'1285','pos'=>'4'),
    array('id'=>'65','name'=>'Athletic','shield'=>'1296','pos'=>'5')
);
```

Pero no se como llegar a esta solución.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: solo por curiosidad pa que tas haciendo esto???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esto creo que responde a tu pregunta, tú te encargas de afinarlo

```
$table = array(
    array('id'=>'25','name'=>'Real Madrid','shield'=>'1234','pos'=>'1'),
    array('id'=>'35','name'=>'Barcelona','shield'=>'1267','pos'=>'2'),
    array('id'=>'45','name'=>'Real Betis','shield'=>'1254','pos'=>'3'),
    array('id'=>'55','name'=>'Villarreal','shield'=>'1285','pos'=>'4'),
    array('id'=>'65','name'=>'Athletic','shield'=>'1296','pos'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'75','name'=>'Atlético','shield'=>'1264','pos'=>'6'),
    array('id'=>'85','name'=>'Osasuna','shield'=>'1265','pos'=>'7'),
    array('id'=>'105','name'=>'Girona','shield'=>'1236','pos'=>'8'),
    array('id'=>'110','name'=>'Rayo Vallecano','shield'=>'1298','pos'=>'9'),
    array('id'=>'10','name'=>'Celta','shield'=>'1274','pos'=>'10'),
    array('id'=>'15','name'=>'R. Sociedad','shield'=>'1342','pos'=>'11'),
    array('id'=>'20','name'=>'Valencia','shield'=>'3214','pos'=>'12'),
    array('id'=>'30','name'=>'Mallorca','shield'=>'1478','pos'=>'13'),
    array('id'=>'40','name'=>'Almería','shield'=>'1463','pos'=>'14'),
    array('id'=>'50','name'=>'Espanyol','shield'=>'1345','pos'=>'15'),
    array('id'=>'60','name'=>'Sevilla','shield'=>'1465','pos'=>'16'),
    array('id'=>'70','name'=>'Real Valladolid','shield'=>'1436','pos'=>'17'),
    array('id'=>'80','name'=>'Getafe','shield'=>'1678','pos'=>'18'),
    array('id'=>'90','name'=>'Elche','shield'=>'8976','pos'=>'19'),
    array('id'=>'100','name'=>'Cádiz','shield'=>'15632','pos'=>'20'),
);

function miniTable($clasificacion, $equipo)
{
    $clave = array_search($equipo, array_column($clasificacion, 'name'));
    $posicion = $clasificacion[$clave]['pos']+1;
    if ($posicion < 4) {
        return GetTabla($clasificacion, 1, 5);
    } elseif ($posicion > 17) {
        return GetTabla($clasificacion, 16 , 20);
    } elseif ($posicion > 3 && $posicion < 18) {
       return GetTabla($clasificacion, $posicion-3, $posicion+1);
    }

    return $minitabla;
}
function GetTabla($clasificacion,$desde,$hasta){
  $minitabla = [];
  $indice=0;
   for($i = $desde-1; $i<$hasta; $i++ ){
      $minitabla[$indice] = $clasificacion[$i];
     $indice++;
   }

}

$equiposelect = miniTable($table,'Mallorca');

var_dump($equiposelect);
```

Comment: QUe se supone que es eso ??? como lo soluciona??? que implementas??? que lo hace diferente?? basado en que documentacion aseguras que esto lo resuelve???

Comment: tratemos de dar respuestas de mejor calidad... no puro codigo... se esta mal acostumbrando a los usuarios que piden algo y les resuelves el codigo completamente sin explicar nada...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 De nuevo lo mismo, te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Creo que fuiste tu el que no lo leiste: "Lee la pregunta cuidadosamente. ¿Qué es lo que se está preguntando específicamente? Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto". En parte dice que hay que poner una referencia bibliográfica a la respuesta o que debes explicar cada línea que pones?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no entiendo tu respuesta, quizás no has leído detenidamente la pregunta inicial. La dificultad residia en que no sabia aplicar la logica para solucionar el problema. Pero a nivel de código una vez visto como se hace el codigo mostrado es realmente claro.

Comment: @Yussef, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ha funcionado justo como esperaba. La verdad es que me gusta mas esta segunda opción y me parece mas clara, que andar "sacando rodajas" (slice) y luego pegando (merge) el resultado.

Comment: no queda claro que hace tu codigo no hay una explicacion .. una respuesta con puro codigo, puro texto o unicamente un link, no es una respuesta de calidad ... y no soy yo el que dice que las respuestas deben ser de calidad ... asi lo dice en [answer]

Comment: pero no se preocupen en 4 horas podran hacer lo que les plasca ... con el sitio como lo vienen haciendo

Comment: Estimado @ArcanisGK507 esto ya lo hablamos. La respuesta es un for, nada más. Todo el resto del código es del OP, no hay mucho que explicar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de `array_slice()` para obtener determinados elementos del array partiendo de una posición tal o cual.

Por otra parte, preferiría determinar la posición usando la clave `pos`, que, supongo, para eso existe en el array.

Finalmente tus comparaciones originales están mal. Si he entendido bien debes comparar si:

- Es menor que 4 (`$posicion < 4`)
- Es mayor que 17 (`$posicion > 17`)
- Está entre 4 y 17 (`$posicion >= 4 && $posicion <= 17`)

Así debería funcionar:

```
$table = array(
    array('id'=>'25','name'=>'Real Madrid','shield'=>'1234','pos'=>'1'),
    array('id'=>'35','name'=>'Barcelona','shield'=>'1267','pos'=>'2'),
    array('id'=>'45','name'=>'Real Betis','shield'=>'1254','pos'=>'3'),
    array('id'=>'55','name'=>'Villarreal','shield'=>'1285','pos'=>'4'),
    array('id'=>'65','name'=>'Athletic','shield'=>'1296','pos'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'75','name'=>'Atlético','shield'=>'1264','pos'=>'6'),
    array('id'=>'85','name'=>'Osasuna','shield'=>'1265','pos'=>'7'),
    array('id'=>'105','name'=>'Girona','shield'=>'1236','pos'=>'8'),
    array('id'=>'110','name'=>'Rayo Vallecano','shield'=>'1298','pos'=>'9'),
    array('id'=>'10','name'=>'Celta','shield'=>'1274','pos'=>'10'),
    array('id'=>'15','name'=>'R. Sociedad','shield'=>'1342','pos'=>'11'),
    array('id'=>'20','name'=>'Valencia','shield'=>'3214','pos'=>'12'),
    array('id'=>'30','name'=>'Mallorca','shield'=>'1478','pos'=>'13'),
    array('id'=>'40','name'=>'Almería','shield'=>'1463','pos'=>'14'),
    array('id'=>'50','name'=>'Espanyol','shield'=>'1345','pos'=>'15'),
    array('id'=>'60','name'=>'Sevilla','shield'=>'1465','pos'=>'16'),
    array('id'=>'70','name'=>'Real Valladolid','shield'=>'1436','pos'=>'17'),
    array('id'=>'80','name'=>'Getafe','shield'=>'1678','pos'=>'18'),
    array('id'=>'90','name'=>'Elche','shield'=>'8976','pos'=>'19'),
    array('id'=>'100','name'=>'Cádiz','shield'=>'15632','pos'=>'20'),
);

function miniTable($clasificacion, $equipo)
{
    $clave = array_search($equipo, array_column($clasificacion, 'name'));
    $posicion = $clasificacion[$clave]['pos'];

    if ($posicion < 4) {
        return array_slice($clasificacion, 0, 5);
    } elseif ($posicion > 17) {
        return array_slice($clasificacion, -5);
    } elseif ($posicion >= 4 && $posicion <= 17) {
        $arrA=array_slice($clasificacion, $posicion-3, 2);
        $arrB=array_slice($clasificacion, $posicion, 2);
        return array_merge($arrA,array($clasificacion[$clave]),$arrB);
    }
}
```

Hagamos algunas pruebas:

```
$equiposelect = miniTable($table,'Real Betis');
var_dump($equiposelect);
```

**Resultado:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Real Madrid"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "35"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Barcelona"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1267"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Real Betis"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1254"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Villarreal"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1285"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "65"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Athletic"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1296"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

---

```
$equiposelect = miniTable($table,'Villarreal');
var_dump($equiposelect);
```

**Resultado:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "35"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Barcelona"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1267"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Real Betis"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1254"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Villarreal"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1285"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "65"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Athletic"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1296"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "75"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Atlético"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1264"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

---

```
$equiposelect = miniTable($table,'Getafe');
var_dump($equiposelect);
```

**Resultado:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "60"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Sevilla"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1465"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "70"
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "Real Valladolid"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1436"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Getafe"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "1678"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "18"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "90"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Elche"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(4) "8976"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "19"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Cádiz"
    ["shield"]=>
    string(5) "15632"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @A-Cedano, pero no entiendo porque las condiciones están mal, X > 3 es igual que X >= 4 y X < 18 es lo mismo que X <= 17. Me puedes explicar la diferencia por favor, esto podría resolver muchas dudas en el futuro.